# WCF Problem Serializing a Message Header

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, datacontract

I have the following code:

```
public virtual void Initialise()
{ 
    this.AddHeader("SystemContext", this.UserSettings.SystemContext);
}

public virtual void AddHeader(string key, object value)
{
    var customHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(key, this.SystemSettings.SystemServiceNamespace, value);
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(customHeader); 
}
```

When I try and execute the server after I have run the above code, I get the following error:

> Type 'ACSIS.Core.Common.Configuration.UserAcountDetials' with data contract name 'UserAcountDetials:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACSIS.Core.Common.Configuration' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the `KnownTypeAttribute` attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Now `UserSettings` describes `SystemContext` as being of type `IDictionary`. I understand that WCF can't magically create objects out of thin air or what ever, so I need to help it out a little.

Is there some way that I can pass the runtime type of object over the wire as well and have it converted back into that type on the other side. I am not using WCF for java to .net SOA stuff or anything like that, I know the concrete type will be on the other side of the wire.

If WCF doesn't really support this (there must be some way though), is there a way I could serialize the data into a binary format, attach the binary to the header and handle serialization myself, using the type information I pass across.

Comment: Why are you using `MessageHeader.CreateHeader` instead of a message contract?

Comment: I would be happy to try as you have suggested, do you have any references I could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try applying the knownType attribute to your service contract, like this:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ACSIS.Core.Common.Configuration.UserAcountDetials))]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{...
```

And yes, while it is less elegant, you could use the BinaryFormatter to serialize your header object into a byte[] array, stick that in the header, then de-serialize on the other side. Binary serialization is tricky when it comes to versioning, so you have to be a bit careful.